# update a database table based on a python list using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a list of `absent_studentID_list`

`absent_studentID_list = ['sid000001','sid000006']`

I want to update a column `status` inside student table which matches the `studentID` with `absent_studentID_list`

currently I'm looping over the list and using update

```
for sid in absent_studentID_list:
        u = update(studentTable).values({"status": "Absent"}).where(studentTable.c.studentid == str(sid))
        studentTableSession.execute(u)
        studentTableSession.commit()
```

Is there a better way to update than this?

Comment: How about `u = studentTable.update().values(status="Absent").where(studentTable.c.studentid.in_(absent_studentID_list))` ? You should only need to execute it once instead of doing it in a loop.

Comment: @GordThompson can you post this answer so that i can accept your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```python
u = studentTable.update()\
    .values(status="Absent")\
    .where(studentTable.c.studentid.in_(absent_studentID_list))
```

By using `in_` you will only need to execute it once instead of doing it in a loop.